# PHP websocket not responding

Tags: php, websocket, wss

Today i create Websocket from PHP docs: second example https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

and i set this to 127.0.0.1 port 6901.
Connection with termianl and javascript script is ok, but I did not get any response.

Comment: I could be wrong, but BSD sockets isn't exactly websockets, maybe you should be looking at Ratchet instead

Comment: @adeneo is right. Web sockets is a protocol that runs over TCP/IP connections, it's not a raw TCP/IP socket... Also, PHP processes are short-lived while Websocket connections have a long life-span. I would move to better suited platforms such as Ruby ( i.e. [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) which I authored or [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com) ) or Javascript (i.e Faye or [socket.io](http://socket.io) ).

Comment: thanks i move to nodejs with socket.io ;)